# how to animate slide in with jQuery without showing content before it's loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

In a few websites developed by me there is a slide-in/fade-in animations of the content once the page is loaded. I use jQuery for that but before the animation it is necessary the content to be hidden. To achieve that first I have used a css rule `#content{display:none}` . Then in the page header in a javascript block `<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#content').css("display","block");

            $('#content').stop().css("margin-top","100%").animate({marginTop:'100%'} ,1300).animate({ marginTop:'5'}, 700,"swing", function(){ 
                $('#loading').fadeOut(); 
...`

If I understand well, the jQuery code executes once the page is loaded and it works well this way, but there is one problem. If the user has no javascript support then the page remains blank because of the hidden with a css content. Also google webmaster tools shows a blank page preview probably because they do not execute the javascript(jQuery) code and also the Safari web browser's Top sites page is with a blank page preview because of the same css rule. So in order to have a full support for non javascript browsers I removed the css rule and instead of that I use a javascript code to hide the content `<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("content").style.display="none"; document.getElementById("loading").style.display="block";</script>` only for the users that has a javascript support but this way if the internet connection is too slow first the content is loading like in a normal page, and once it is loaded then the browsers hides it and the animation is executed. This is annoying because this way the animation is bothering the user experience instead of improving it. You  start reading the page and suddenly the page disappears and slide in... You can see the result here - http://sky-camp.com/en/paragliding-courses.html

What do I miss? I use javascript for content hiding instead of jQuery in order to try to hide the content before the jQuery plugin is loaded, but It does not work the way I expect.. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: This is a great question. I'm not sure I know the answer, but the amount of people that disable javascript these days is next to none. People with a slower connection is a much more likely problem to come across, so if there is no solution to this question I recommend sticking with `display:none` in CSS rather than tweaking the user experience just to cater to a few people who disable javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing something in the head like:

```
<script>document.write('<style>#content{display:none;}</style>');</script>
```

I haven't don't that in a long time, but I used to use it often.

Comment: I do the same thing. I'll have a "preloader" div fixed over the whole page so content is still crawl able, and once the required functions are executed destroy it.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! I checked the error console and for some reason there was an error "null" is not an object ... while evaluating getElementById("content"). In another html5 site I need to hide the nav tag before the page is loaded and this will help also, cause I can add any style instead of looking for missing javascript selectors for html5 tags. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
<code>
$( function(){$('#content').css("display","none"); });
</code>
```

when your page charge completly:

```
<code>
$(window).load(function() {
$( function(){$('#content').css("display","block");
});
</code>
```

Comment: a bit better experience with this code adjustment but again some of the pages are shown for a moment and hidden until the page is loaded. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is just my opinion...

But I don't really ever prepare for people disabling javascript. As somebody already said, who still does that? If they did there web experience would be awful. Why don't you just add a noscript tag that bypasses that whole function and just shows the content. So if anybody ever does visit the site without JS they just see the page normally.

I feel all the suggestions people have been posting are horribly gross and not at all good practice.

Comment: It's not good to force people to use js cause the most of them use it. What if they cannot enable js cause they use internet in some computer they do not have admin rights or even they do not know what is javascript in order to enable. Do they need to be familiar with all tech stuff in order to access the content of the website? I think it's not. Of course with jQuery animations the sites look much better, but some people do not care about such experience they just need the information and I think it is not a good practice just to ignore them, because they are too small part of all.

Comment: You are not wrong, and i'm not saying you are wrong, but i have never in my 10 years doing this encountered anybody who disabled javascript or had it disabled. Nor have i never seen any analytics with people having JS turned off. I really feel it's not something we need to worry about anymore especially with how much javascript plays a role in todays web.